# how to write Spark data frame to Neo4j database

Tags: apache-spark, neo4j, apache-spark-sql

I'd like to build this workflow:

- preprocess some data with Spark, ending with a data frame
- write such dataframe to Neo4j as a set of nodes

My idea is really basic:  write each row in the df as a node, where each column value represents the value of the node's attribute

I have seen many articles, including [neo4j-spark-connector](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-spark-connector) and [Introducing the Neo4j 3.0 Apache Spark Connector](https://neo4j.com/blog/neo4j-3-0-apache-spark-connector/) but they all focus on importing into Spark data from a Neo4j db... so far, I wasn't able to find a clear example of writing a Spark data frame to a Neo4j database.

Any pointer to documentation or very basic examples are much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Read this issue](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-spark-connector/issues/27) to answer my question.

Long story short, neo4j-spark-connector can write Spark data to Neo4j db, and yes, there is a lack in the documentation of the new release.

Comment: Yes true, sorry, I meant to come back and add more docs and implementations for writing back the data. Hope it still worked out for you.

Comment: @user299791 Did you succed ?

Answer (score 1):

you can write some routine and use an opensource neo4j java driver

https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-java-driver

for example.

Simple serialise the result of an RDD (using rdd.toJson) and then use the above driver to create your neo4j nodes and push into your neo4j instance.

Comment: I'd rather use the neo4j-spark-connector, don't want to make too many jumps... I am sure it's not a big deal, it's just a lack of documentation

Comment: well neo4j-spark-connector is just for pulling data from neo4j into spark (not vice versa) (proof is in the code https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-spark-connector/blob/master/src/main/java/org/neo4j/spark/Neo4JavaSparkContext.java), - it uses neo4j-java-driver to do this under the bonnet, so you probably already have neo4j-java-driver as a dependant lib in your build.

Comment: https://neo4j.com/developer/apache-spark/#preprocessing possibly have a look at this blog: http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2015/04/14/spark-generating-csv-files-to-import-into-neo4j/ - this is an alternative for generating CSV's to import back into neo4j if you dont want to go the driver import route. It does mean that you have to export to file as part of your data pipeline, but if you are just prototyping, maybe the quickest win

Comment: thanks for your time and for your explanations, the CSV route looks really cumbersome but maybe less error prone, while the neo4j-java-driver doesn't seem to have much docs or examples so I don't know how to use that information... you suggest to convert my data frame to a JSON and then to store the JSON into the db... I'll search for example...

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is pretty old but I don't think the neo4j-spark-connector can solve your issue. The full story, sample code and the details are available [here](https://lansalo.com/2020/01/09/how-not-to-persist-spark-dataset-dataframe-toneo4j-and-how-to/) but to cut the long story short if you look carefully at the [Neo4jDataFrame.mergeEdgeList](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-spark-connector/issues/27) example (which has been suggested), you'll noticed that what it does is to instantiate a driver for each row in the dataframe. That will work in a unit test with 10 rows but you can't expect it to work in a real case scenario with millions or billions of rows. Besides there are other defects explained in the link above where you can find a csv based solution. Hope it helps.